# In my viewDidAppear, how do I know when it's being unwound by a child?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

When my child performs an unwind segue, my controller's viewDidAppear gets called.

In this method (and this method alone, I need to know whether it was from an unwind or not)

Note: the child is unwinding to the very first view controller, so this is an **intermediate** view controller, not the true root.

Comment: It will get `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: But how do I know it was from an unwind instead of something else?

Comment: I'm not really sure why you'd put these two things together.... They're more or less mutually exclusive other than the fact that the unwind segue is the one who initiates the unwind process. But to your question.... Technically yes. It's important to remember that `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` will be called whenever the view appears. Regardless if it was cased by an unwind segue.

Comment: Can't you just set a flag in unwind IBAction and access it in viewDidAppear?

Comment: It's important because I have something that's called in viewDidAppear (and I can't call it in viewDidLoad because it involves performSegue, and you can't call performSegue in viewDidLoad).

Comment: @lxx I updated my question :) this is actually an intermediate view controller, not the absolute root. The child is unwinding all the way to the absolute beginning of the universe.

Comment: Not sure if this works but you could trigger unwind first to your intermediate controller and then immediately another one to the root controller?

Comment: maybe it's easier to just use delegation or notification in your case ?

Comment: Anyway having some problems imagining the use case, if you want to unwind to the root view controller why should the intermediate controller appear? will viewDidAppear even be called?

Comment: @lxx, yes, viewDidAppear will be called on B when C rewinds to A.

Comment: Are you sure? From what I understand in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html this doesn't seem to be the case. It looks like it's a direct transition between source and destination controller. It also wouldn't really make sense to trigger viewWillAppear on the intermediate view controllers, as they will never "appear".

Comment: Actually it will call intermediate VC viewDidAppear.

Comment: Maybe using singleton to keep flag ? and access it in viewDidAppear ?

Comment: Can you not use the methods `isMovingFromParentViewController`, `isMovingToParentViewController`, `isBeingPresented` and `isBeingDismissed` to work out if the controller is being shown for the first time or exposed as a result of an unwind which really just results in a pop for nav controllers and a dismiss for modals? That is what they are for and what I use to detect returns from pushed controllers.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to use the following to detect in each controller if the exposure of the view controller was as a result of being pushed/presented, or as a result of being exposed as a result of pop/dismiss/unwind.

This may or may be enough for your needs.

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Handle controller being exposed from push/present or pop/dismiss
    if (self.isMovingToParentViewController || self.isBeingPresented){
        // Controller is being pushed on or presented.
    }
    else{
        // Controller is being shown as result of pop/dismiss/unwind.
    }
}
```

If you want to know that `viewDidAppear` was called because of an unwind segue as being different from a conventional pop/dismiss being called, then you need to add some code to detect that an unwind happened. To do this you could do the following:

For any intermediate controller you want to detect purely an unwind in, add a property of the form:

```
/** BOOL property which when TRUE indicates an unwind occured. */
@property BOOL unwindSeguePerformed;
```

Then override the unwind segue method `canPerformUnwindSegueAction:fromViewController:withSender:` method as follows:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformUnwindSegueAction:(SEL)action
                 fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController
                         withSender:(id)sender{
  // Set the flag indicating an unwind segue was requested and then return
  // that we are not interested in performing the unwind action.
  self.unwindSeguePerformed = TRUE;

  // We are not interested in performing it, so return NO. The system will
  // then continue to look backwards through the view controllers for the 
  // controller that will handle it.
  return NO;
}
```

Now you have a flag to detect an unwind and a means to detect the unwind just before it happens. Then adjust the `viewDidAppear` method to include this flag.

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Handle controller being exposed from push/present or pop/dismiss
    // or an unwind
    if (self.isMovingToParentViewController || self.isBeingPresented){
        // Controller is being pushed on or presented.
        // Initialize the unwind segue tracking flag.
        self.unwindSeguePerformed = FALSE;
    }
    else if (self.unwindSeguePerformed){
        // Controller is being shown as a result of an unwind segue
    }
    else{
        // Controller is being shown as result of pop/dismiss.
    }
}
```

Hopefully this meets your requirement.

For docs on handling the unwind segue chain see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html

Comment: Updated answer with full solution to include detecting unwind versus pop/dismiss.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `self.isMovingToParentViewController || self.isBeingPresented` is true when the `viewDidAppear:` is called while popping the view controller. (yes, I'm sure it's the popping view controller, not the one behind)

Comment: Indeed, the answer is wrong. Seems like this has changed since it was written in 2015?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple category on UIViewController that you can use to track whether your presented view controller is in the midst of an unwind segue.  I suppose it could be flushed out more but I believe this much works for your case.

To use it you need to register the unwind segue from your unwind action method on the destination view controller:

```
- (IBAction) prepareForUnwind:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    [self ts_registerUnwindSegue: segue];
}
```

That's it.  From your intermediate view controller, you can test if you are in the midst of an unwind segue:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear: animated];

    BOOL unwinding = [self ts_isUnwinding];

    NSLog( @"%@:%@, unwinding: %@", self.title, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), unwinding ? @"YES" : @"NO" );
}
```

There's no need to clean anything up; the segue will self-deregister when it ends.

Here's the full category:

```
@interface UIViewController (unwinding)

- (void) ts_registerUnwindSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue*) segue;
- (BOOL) ts_isUnwinding;

@end


static NSMapTable* g_viewControllerSegues;

@implementation UIViewController (unwinding)

- (void) ts_registerUnwindSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue*) segue
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

        g_viewControllerSegues = [NSMapTable weakToWeakObjectsMapTable];
    });

    for ( UIViewController* vc = segue.sourceViewController ; vc != nil ; vc = vc.presentingViewController )
    {
        [g_viewControllerSegues setObject: segue forKey: vc];
    }
}

- (BOOL) ts_isUnwinding
{
    return [g_viewControllerSegues objectForKey: [self ts_topMostParentViewController]] != nil;
}

- (UIViewController *)ts_topMostParentViewController {
    UIViewController *viewController = self;
    while (viewController.parentViewController) {
        viewController = viewController.parentViewController;
    }
    return viewController;
}

@end
```

Comment: vc.presentingViewController will be nil except for modal presentation or when some ancestor was presented as a modal.  e.g This will not work for NavRoot->A->PushB->PushC with unwind from C to A, detect at B as there is no `presentingViewController`. `ts_registerUnwindSegue` would need to use the same algorithm which the unwind segue search code uses to locate the target controller which would include searching children of the source controllers navigation controller, navigation parents, modals and combinations of each.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel - IMO this question pertains to presented (modal) controllers, not controllers pushed onto a UINavigationController stack.  Why?  Because unwinding from a nav-stack doesn't invoke the intermediate controller's viewDidAppear methods.

Comment: Looking at this again, your assumption looks correct.

Comment: This is a good work around, thanks. However I tested it and the implementation is not correct imo. As all children of a given presentingViewController will also have viewDidAppear called as a side effect of its parent having it called on itself, any child controller of the presentingViewController won't be found by the category. I'll suggest a edit in your question to fix it as it won't fit in a comment and I don't think it is worth an answer as the logic is all yours.

Answer (score 1):

Your question was really interesting to me, because I never used IB and segues before (don't judge me for that) and wanted to learn something new. As you described in your comments:

> **viewDidAppear** will be called on `B` when `C` rewinds to `A`

So I come up with an easy custom solution to this:

```
protocol ViewControllerSingletonDelegate: class {

    func viewControllerWillUnwind(viewcontroller: UIViewController, toViewController: UIViewController)
}

class ViewControllerSingleton {

    static let sharedInstance = ViewControllerSingleton()

    private var delegates: [ViewControllerSingletonDelegate] = []

    func addDelegate(delegate: ViewControllerSingletonDelegate) {

        if !self.containsDelegate(delegate) {

            self.delegates.append(delegate)
        }
    }

    func removeDelegate(delegate: ViewControllerSingletonDelegate) {

        /* implement any other function by your self :) */
    }

    func containsDelegate(delegate: ViewControllerSingletonDelegate) -> Bool {

        for aDelegate in self.delegates {

            if aDelegate === delegate { return true }
        }

        return false
    }

    func forwardToDelegate(closure: (delegate: ViewControllerSingletonDelegate) -> Void) {

        for aDelegate in self.delegates { closure(delegate: aDelegate) }
    }
}


class SomeViewController: UIViewController, ViewControllerSingletonDelegate {

    let viewControllerSingleton = ViewControllerSingleton.sharedInstance

    func someFunction() { // some function where you'll set the delegate

        self.viewControllerSingleton.addDelegate(self)
    }

    /* I assume you have something like this in your code */
    @IBAction func unwindToSomeOtherController(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

        self.viewControllerSingleton.forwardToDelegate { (delegate) -> Void in

            delegate.viewControllerWillUnwind(unwindSegue.sourceViewController, toViewController: unwindSegue.destinationViewController)
        }

        /* do something here */
    }

    // MARK: - ViewControllerSingletonDelegate
    func viewControllerWillUnwind(viewcontroller: UIViewController, toViewController: UIViewController) {

        /* do something with the callback */
        /* set some flag for example inside your view controller so your viewDidAppear will know what to do */
    }
}
```

You also could modify the callback function to return something else, like controller identifier instead the controller itself.

I do everything programmatically, so please don't judge me for that too. ;)

If this code snippet won't help you, I'd still love to see some feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the segue navigation is ViewController -> FirstViewController -> SecondViewController. There is an unwind from `SecondViewController` to `ViewController`. You can add in the intermediary `FirstViewController` the following code to detect unwind actions.

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    var unwindAction:Bool = false
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if unwindAction {
            println("Unwind action")
            unwindAction = false
        }
    }
    override func viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction(action: Selector, fromViewController: UIViewController, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> UIViewController? {
        self.unwindAction = true

         return super.viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction(action, fromViewController: fromViewController, withSender: sender)
    }

}
```

**EDIT**
After giving this some thought, I decided the solution to this depends on the kind of complexity that you are dealing with here. What exactly do you do when you do the unwind segue? The solutions given here are viable and they work -- only if you want to detect whether it is an unwind action. What if you want to pass the data between the point where the unwind is happening to the root? What if there is a complex set of preparations that you wanna do in one of the intermediate view controllers? What if you want to do both of these?

In such complex scenarios, I would immediately rule out overriding the unwind methods of the view controller. Doing such operations there will work, but it won't be clean. A method will be doing what it isn't supposed to do. Smell that? That's code smell.

What if, somehow a view controller could inform the next view controller in the hierarchy of the event happening? Better yet, how do we do this without tightly coupling these two?

Protocol.

Have a protocol definition something like:

```
protocol UnwindResponding {
    prepareForUnwindSegue(segue:UISegue , formViewController:UIViewController, withImportantInfo info:[String,AnyObject])
}
```

Using protocol you will keep the relationship between the objects -- the hierarchy of view controllers in this case -- explicit. At the point of occurrence of a particular event, you will delegate the call to the next controller in the hierarchy informing about the happening of a particular event in another view controller. Here is an example:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue:UIStoryboardSegue, sender:AnyObject?) {

    if let unwindResponder = self.presentingViewController as? UnwindResponding where segue.identifier = "unwindSegue" {
        unwindResponder.prepareForUnwindSegue(segue:UISegue, fromViewController:self,info:info)
    }


}
```

In the intermediary view controller you can do something like:

```
extension IntermediaryViewController : UnwindResponding {
    prepareForUnwindSegue(segue:UISegue , fromViewController:UIViewController, withImportantInfo info:[String,AnyObject]) {
        if let unwindResponder =  self.presentingViewController {
            unwindResponder.prepareForUnwindSegue(segue,fromViewController:fromViewController, info:info)
        }
        unwindSegue = true
    }
}
```

Granted, you wouldn't wanna do this if you just want to detect unwind segues. Maybe you do, you'll never know what will happen in the future. Never hurts to keep your code clean.

Comment: I do not believe `viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction` will be called in FirstViewController in the case of Push->Push. The documetation states that this method is called on the controller which starts the unwind and for a controller pushed, this will return the parent which is the navigation controller. Then `canPerformUnwindSegueAction` is called on its children. The only reliable mechanism is to use `canPerformUnwindSegueAction` to detect the unwind in all controllers. See my answer.

Comment: All right. Yes. But why would you do an unwind segue in navigation controller systems? Seems like an overkill to me.

Comment: The important piece is that if you just pop to a controller, its harder to pass information back and you have to do all the code. Unwind segues give you a mechanism to pass information to the point you jump back to before the jump happens and its all done by IB. There are lots of examples where you might want to select an item which requires more than one controller push to reach: When selected you want to jump back to the controller which started the selection off. The other advantage is it also works across push and modal sequences without you having to write code.

Comment: I would prefer writing a lot of code especially since with the given approach there is tight coupling between the controllers. I would rather delegate with explicit relationship between root/descendant. But then again, this approach works for simple situations. +1, your answer. :)

Comment: I think the idea is the tight coupling is reduced to the use of proper unwind target methods: e.g. prepareForUnwindAsColorSelected, prepareForUnwindAsNameSelected etc... So I actually quite like that the coding is reduce to setting up the contract between unwind activation and appropriate unwind to points without needing any code added to the intermediate controllers. So I think that the relationship is explicit as long as you use a suitable naming scheme: same as you would have to do if doing it all by hand. Appreciate the +1 8^).

Comment: Establishing explicit relationship by mere naming scheme? Are you sure? I would rather use a protocol to make the relationships explicit.

Comment: Saw your update. Unfortunately `presentingViewController` is nil except if using modal presentation: or worse is set to the presenter of a modal ancestor which could skip some of the controllers in between. For a controller which is pushed, `self.navigationController` is the equivalent but then you need find the previous child by looking through its controller stack. This is actually what the unwind segue mechanism does as it hunts for the controller which has the right action method. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html

Comment: The point is not that. The point is that it is very easy if you follow the protocol mechanism. You can make any class confirm to this protocol and have unwind messages sent there. The presentingViewController example taken here is just an example of this approach.

Comment: I got the idea. My point is that it is short circuiting the iOS unwind mechanism. The iOS unwind algorithm will end at the first instance which implements the protocol. Your protocol has now taken over the unwind process. This controller (which now knows the unwind has happened:tick)) now has to have code to find the next controller which implements the protocol which may or may not be the TRUE endpoint of the unwind segue. This means every intermediate when called has to code the full iOS unwind point search algorithm to get the next controller to retain the integrity of the unwind.

Answer (score 1):

Add  method in your parent view controller

```
@IBAction func unwindToParent(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let childViewController = unwindSegue.sourceViewController as? ChildViewController {
        println("unwinding from child")
    }
}
```

As an exemple if the unwind segue is related to a button, in the storyboard link your button to it's view controller exit

[image]

It will propose to link to unwindToParent method

[image]

Then each time the unwind segue is performed, the `unwindToParent` method will be called

Answer (score 0):

You can override the function `unwindForSegue:towardsViewController:`, which is called when the ViewController is on the path of an unwind segue. It's meant to be used to reconfigure the ViewController.

Swift example:

```
override func unwind(for unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue, towardsViewController subsequentVC: UIViewController) {
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see `unwindForSegue:towardsViewController:` being called on any of the view controllers in the path of an unwind (iOS 12.1).