# Swift iOS , call function after popToRootViewViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

This is a very simple and straightforward question but I can't seem to phrase it correctly to find what I'm looking for.

I'm currently using a navigation controller. The navigation controller has a root view and two views pushed on top of that root view.

I'm using

```
_ = navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

to pop those two views and go back to my root view.

I would like to call a function after transitioning back to my main view. Is there a function that I can override in my root view to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `view[Will|Did]Appear`?

Comment: Yep, that will do it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could override the `viewDidAppear` / `viewWillAppear` and use the `isBeingPresented` property

You can check here for an example

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31612271/2585955

Comment: Awesome that's exactly what I was looking for. I'm very new to iOS so that wasn't quite as obvious, for me, as it should have been.