# Viewdidappear isn't calling when return from child view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I know this is a dummy question but I don't know what is the problem. I have two viewcontrollers, one of them is opening as a popup. When I click close button in popup, I call unwind segue but viewdidappear function isn't calling in my parent viewcontroller.
 I got help from this post. [Unwound by a child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618424/in-my-viewdidappear-how-do-i-know-when-its-being-unwound-by-a-child/31612271#31612271)

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    // Handle controller being exposed from push/present or pop/dismiss
    if (self.isMovingToParentViewController || self.isBeingPresented){
        // Controller is being pushed on or presented.
        print("hello")
    }
    else{
        // Controller is being shown as result of pop/dismiss/unwind.
        print("hello2")
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated but make sure you call `super.viewDidAppear(animated)`.

Comment: I'm doing it already :(

Comment: First of all, in the question you are not doing what rmaddy suggested. Secondly can you please put breakpoint to that line and tell us if it did stop the application.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it via delegate and protocol.

In secondviewcontroller which is tableviewcontroller:

```
protocol TableViewControllerDelegate { 
    func controller(_ controller: TableViewController, didAddItem: String)
}
class TableViewController:  UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    var delegate: TableViewControllerDelegate?
    ...
```

In segue part of secondviewcontroller

```
delegate?.controller(self, didAddItem: "hello")
```

In firstviewcontroller:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, TableViewControllerDelegate{

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Segue" {
            let destination = segue.destination as? TableViewController
            if let viewController = destination
            {
                viewController.delegate = self as TableViewControllerDelegate
            }
        }
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    // MARK: Add Item View Controller Delegate Methods

    func controller(_ controller: TableViewController, didAddItem: String) {
        // Update Data Source

        // Reload Table View
        mainStackView.isHidden = false
        // Dismiss Add Item View Controller
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```